# Stripe: Subscription and recurring plans

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

I want to know is there any scenario supported by stripe with recurring plans, 
If a user subscribes to a plan A that costs $300 and its billing cycle is 3 months and he/she upgrades to 
a new plan i.e., Plan B costs $600 i.e., also for 3 months recurring period, after 1 month or less subscription period of using plan A then we need
to upgrade that user to plan B with following conditions:

-100$ should be deducated from 300$ for 1 month or less than 30 days and 200 will be remaining in his wallet
-He/she will have to pay 600-200(Remaining from plan A payment)=400$ for the new plan i.e., Plan B
-Similarly, if He/she subscribed to plan B first then he can also subscribe to plan A after the usage of 1 month or less
than 30 days then the deducated amount from his wallet would be 600/3=200$ the deducated amount will be 200$ and the remaining amount is
400$ that will be added in his wallet then if he/she subscribed to plan A then there will be deductions of 300 from 400$ which is in his/her wallet now
so his/her remaining balance will be 100$.
-Please explain is it possible with the stripe? If yes then please help me for this issue.
Sorry for the english grammatical mistakes
Thank you

Comment: Yes it is possible, but I’d give the Stripe docs a read – it’s all in there. This isn’t a technical issue I’m afraid. In Stripe you can have more than one subscription at the same time, so it’s up to you how you decide to make this work. This will get you started: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/multiplan

Comment: Yes it is possible, but I’d give the Stripe docs a read – it’s all in there. This isn’t a technical issue I’m afraid. In Stripe you can have more than one subscription at the same time, so it’s up to you how you decide to make this work. This will get you started: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/multiplan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update a subscription, there is a `prorate` option, which defaults to `true`, so that the user will automatically be charged for any difference in the price of the new plan, adjusted for their time in the current billing period.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription-prorate

That should be all that's required for your first example.

I don't totally follow on your other examples, but it seems that you could simplify it by simply using multiple plans.

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/multiplan

Generally, either you have different tiers of plans, which users might upgrade/downgrade, in which case you likely just want to update their existing subscription with proration. Or, if users might be subscribing to multiple plans at the same time, then you would simply allow users to sign up for multiple plans, which Stripe fully supports. There shouldn't be much of a reason to try to do both at once for the same set of plans.